# fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory, x86_64-w64-mingw32 mode

Tags: c, linux, sockets, cygwin, mingw-w64

I am trying to develop a program which depends on socket library, once i am trying to make it, it prompt me:

```
fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/socket.h>
```

My build environment:
Windows 8.1 under Cygwin x64 version,
Build target: x86_64-w64-mingw32 as the --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 parameters.

Command Line: cfalgs=-m64 ./configure --prefix=/usr/

I am building the app which is using the GTK+ 2.0.

I am trying to find the find under the socket.h file under the patch: cygwin64\usr\x86_64-w64-mingw32\sys-root\mingw\include\sys.  It seems not exist at all.

So there is no x64 version MinGW socket lib??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sys/socket.h` is a POSIX/SUS header. MinGW is for building WinAPI executables. Either switch to building with Cygwin's GCC to get access to POSIX/SUS facilities, or switch to using WinAPI's `winsock2.h` instead.

Comment: Yup, I think it should be the problem what you mentioned. Actually, i tried to build it as Cygwin mode, it works with X11 server. So now, i would like build an independent edition on Windows platform. So i probably need to reverse to include winsock2.h as well.

Comment: @Ignacio, But if it is compiled using cygwin, would the executable run fine on Windows?