# sys/socket.h missing compiling with libpq on windows mingw

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, libpq

When I am trying to compile my project that uses `libpq-fe.h` and MinGW, I get the following error. I also see that the folder `postgresql/server/port/win32` has the file `sys/socket.h`, but when I try to add that as an included directory I am met with a more complex error.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/postgresql/server/getaddrinfo.h:25:10: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
25 | #include <sys/socket.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compile options are you using?

Comment: Does the user you are compiling as have permissions on that directory?

Comment: According to this entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736266/fatal-error-sys-socket-h-no-such-file-or-directory-x86-64-w64-mingw32-mode you might need to use `winsock2.h` instead.

Comment: @wohlstad I saw that, but I don't see why I would have to modify the source for a msys2 package for it to work? That was my thought process at least...